# PyCharm error when connecting to PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc, pycharm, database-connection

I'm getting this error when trying to connect to a PostgreSQL 9.4 database running on Heroku/AWS:

```
The specified database user/password combination is rejected:
[28000] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "X.X.X.X", user "XXX", database "XXX"
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Open the database connection settings, click on the "Advanced" tab and values to the following parameters:

`ssl` = `false`

`sslfactory` = `org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`

Click Apply and Test Connection.

Credits: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205996299/comments/206373089

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Advanced` tab and look for the `sslmode` key. Set this to `require` from the dropdown and you should be good to go.

As a side note, if you got here by just googling `postgres pycharm not connecting to db` or something, it would probably be helpful to point out that I failed to make the connection by just pasting the connection string into the `URL` field. I had to manually break it down for each of the fields for it to finally connect.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - this ```sslmode``` was exactly what my issue was.
Thanks @karuhanga